# How to calculate latitude using sun

Tags: geometry

The Earth is tilted 23.45° north or south in the summer and winter solstices and directly above the equator in the equinoxes.
But in the dates between the solstices and equinoxes, how do I calculate the tilt of of Earth.
(Dates and degrees create a sine wave pattern on graph)

Comment: Do you want to calculate latitude, or the tilt of the earth?

Comment: Latitude but I am having problems calculating the tilt of Earth.

Comment: It's not quite a sine wave, because the Earth's orbit is not circular (and therefore the direction to the Sun changes faster at some times than at others).

Comment: That is exactly the problem I am having in Calculating the latitude. Can you give a solution to this problem assuming that it's a circular orbit.